# Python compare timestamp to input time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have some dataframe with timestamps as a column, I want to filter rows between 8:00:00 to 17:00:00 with np.where. I keep getting error messages on data/object types. Any help would be appreciated

example:

```
timestamp    volume
2013-03-01 07:59:00    5
2013-03-01 08:00:00    6
2013-03-01 08:01:00    7
2013-03-01 08:02:00    8
```

Basically I want to end with:

```
2013-03-01 08:00:00    6
2013-03-01 08:01:00    7
2013-03-01 08:02:00    8
```

By using methods along the line of

```
np.where(df['timestamp'] > dt.time('8:00:00')
```

Comment: Post the error messages you've been getting: they often times will tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: What is the `df['timestamp'].dtpye`?

Comment: You're going to want to use `>=` if the second row should make it into the result set. Also, `df[df.timestamp > '08:00:00']` should work whether the dtype is object or datetime.

Comment: `df.set_index('timestamp').between_time('08:00','17:00').reset_index()`?

Comment: df['timestamp'].dtype shows dtype('O').  I tried the df[df.timestamp > '08:00:00'] but no luck - table returns empty dataframe   np.where(df['timestamp'] > dt.time('8:00:00') yields:  TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'

Comment: Yep, I checked and I had the YYYY-mm-dd portion of your timestamp in my index, which is threw off my answer. As the answers below suggest, you're probably best off converting `df.timestamp` to datetime, especially if you need to compare a large number of dates. If you can include the date in your string (i.e. you're looking at timestamps for a single day), then you can do `df[df.timestamp >= '2013-03-01 08:00:00']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [226]: df
Out[226]:
             timestamp  volume
0  2013-03-01 07:59:00       5
1  2013-03-01 08:00:00       6
2  2013-03-01 08:01:00       7
3  2013-03-01 08:02:00       8

In [227]: df.dtypes
Out[227]:
timestamp    object
volume        int64
dtype: object

In [228]: df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], errors='coerce')

In [229]: df.dtypes
Out[229]:
timestamp    datetime64[ns]  # <---- it's `datetime64[ns]` now
volume                int64
dtype: object

In [230]: df.set_index('timestamp').between_time('08:00','17:00').reset_index()
Out[230]:
            timestamp  volume
0 2013-03-01 08:00:00       6
1 2013-03-01 08:01:00       7
2 2013-03-01 08:02:00       8
```

Comment: I was able to run this until I look at my result pivot table and saw time before 8:00:00 still.  My data contains multiple days so I wonder if this would work? I printed my resulting data into csv and still see time stamps outside of this period.

Comment: my mistake, forgot to set the dataframe to update. this worked well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `between`

I Generated a sample dataframe with

```
import datetime
d = {'timestamp': pd.Series([datetime.datetime.now() + 
          datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(20)]),
    'volume': pd.Series([s for s in range(20)])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

`df['timeframe']` is

```
0    2017-02-13 22:37:54.515840
1    2017-02-13 23:37:54.515859
2    2017-02-14 00:37:54.515865
3    2017-02-14 01:37:54.515870
4    2017-02-14 02:37:54.515878
5    2017-02-14 03:37:54.515884
6    2017-02-14 04:37:54.515888
...
17   2017-02-14 15:37:54.515939
18   2017-02-14 16:37:54.515943
19   2017-02-14 17:37:54.515948
```

`df.dtypes`

```
timestamp    datetime64[ns]
volume                int64
dtype: object
```

As in your example `dtype` of `df['timestamp']`is `object` you can do

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], coerce=True)
```

By setting param `coerce=True` if the conversion fails for any particular string then those rows are set to `NaT`.

Then filtering can be done using `between` as below

`df[df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('11:00:00','18:00:00')]`
will return

```
13 2017-02-14 11:37:54.515922      13
14 2017-02-14 12:37:54.515926      14
15 2017-02-14 13:37:54.515930      15
16 2017-02-14 14:37:54.515935      16
17 2017-02-14 15:37:54.515939      17
18 2017-02-14 16:37:54.515943      18
19 2017-02-14 17:37:54.515948      19
```

Comment: it didn't work as my timestamp dtype was object instead of datetime64[ns]. Got error: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Can you try `df['date time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], coerce=True)` before the filtering ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a file with data as below :
timestamp          volume
2013-03-01 07:59:00    5
2013-03-01 08:00:00    6
2013-03-01 08:01:00    7
2013-03-01 08:02:00    8

Then while reading only you can skip the first line and you will get output as 
timestamp           volume
2013-03-01 08:00:00    6
2013-03-01 08:01:00    7
2013-03-01 08:02:00    8

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("filename",skiprows=1)
print(df)
```